# Zend Framework redirect in front controller plugin causes redirect loop

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, apache2

```
class Ef_AppSecurity extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        if (!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity())
        {
            $redirect = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
            $redirect->gotoSimpleAndExit('login', 'auth');
        }
    }
}
```

It redirects and changes to the new url however in the browser it creates a redirect loop. I'm wondering if the problem could stem from the apache mod_rewrite settings.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not append that plugin on login/auth, *or*; extend the criteria to

```
if (!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()
     && $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() != 'login'
     && $this->getRequest()->getActionName() != 'auth')
```

Comment: @eforth glad I could help! Feel free to mark any answer as "correct" to make the "case closed".

Answer (score 0):

You must add a exception for the login page. Otherwise that will be redirected as well back on to itself causing the loop.

So if your login page is in the controller called 'login' and 'index' action you need to add a exception for that page and any other page with might handle the form.

```
    if (!Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity() 
        && $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() != 'login'
        && $this->getRequest()->getActionName() != 'index')
        )
    {
        $redirect = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
        $redirect->gotoSimpleAndExit('login', 'index');
    }
```

Comment: Isn' this exactly what I posted? Except that you got the action wrong.

Comment: Thanks paulrichards19 for an explanation as to why i was getting the loop.